# Docker Compose only takes the first word in multiline command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run a multiline command when starting a container in docker compose:

```
services:
  foo:
    image: alpine:edge
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    command: >
      apk add --no-cache curl
```

Running `docker compose up` gives me the following errors:

```
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Network tmps6nvvhf0ms_default  Created                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 ✔ Container tmps6nvvhf0ms-foo-1  Created                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
Attaching to foo-1
foo-1  | apk-tools 2.14.0, compiled for aarch64.
foo-1  |
foo-1  | usage: apk [<OPTIONS>...] COMMAND [<ARGUMENTS>...]
foo-1  |
foo-1  | Package installation and removal:
foo-1  |   add        Add packages to WORLD and commit changes
foo-1  |   del        Remove packages from WORLD and commit changes
...
...
```

It's clear that only the first word `apk` was passed to `docker compose`. I tried with other commands and they have the same results.

`docker version`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.21.3
 Git commit:        afdd53b4e3
 Built:             Thu Oct 26 07:06:42 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           colima

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.10
  Git commit:       311b9ff
  Built:            Thu Oct 26 09:08:29 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.25
  GitCommit:        d8f198a4ed8892c764191ef7b3b06d8a2eeb5c7f
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.10
  GitCommit:        v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

`docker compose version`

```
Docker Compose version 2.23.3
```

Comment: Just as an aside: executing package installation at container runtime is always a smell. If possible, I would suggest installing the package at image build time.

Comment: With my dev hat on, i'd agree @Turing85, with my devops hat on, no: Building an image now incurs a huge cost of ensuring that the image is rebuilt often as the base image changes. 
Layering some package installation at container runtime means you can be sure to track upstream image updates with, essentially, zero cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, this form is convenient:

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    image: alpine:edge
    command: 
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      apk add --no-cache curl
      curl http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you specify the command as a string, it is subjected to shell splitting. Given the fragment in your question, you end up with the following invocation:

```
/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache curl
```

Whereas you meant:

```
/bin/sh -c "apk add --no-cache curl"
```

One way to accomplish that is by specifying an array for `command`, which disables shell splitting:

```
services:
  foo:
    command:
      - apk add --no-cache curl
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Botje indicates in [their answer](/a/77659205), Compose splits a multi-word `command:` into separate words for you, but `sh -c` only expects a single word as its input.

I'd address this by just deleting the `entrypoint:` override.  The YAML block scalar (multiline string) syntax isn't special here.

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    image: alpine:edge
    command: apk add --no-cache curl
```

Note that the `command:` gets repeated every time you start the container.  It's not usually a good practice to install software inside a running container, since that will be lost as soon as the container exits.  A better approach is to do the installation once as part of building a custom image.  The Compose file becomes even simpler

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    build: .
    # no image:, entrypoint:, command:
```

and in the same directory, a Dockerfile

```bash
FROM alpine:edge             # was Compose image:
RUN apk add --no-cache curl  # was Compose command:
CMD ???                      # what should the container _actually_ do?
```

This also has the advantage of it being easy to have multiple `RUN` lines, which run in order, and of the `RUN` lines *actually* being processed by a shell.